# Should *ngFor be used by templates internally, or should it be used externally?

Tags: angular

I've seen *ngFor used to repeat child templates from the parent template, and also seen it used inside the child template itself. Is there a situation in which either of these should be preferred?

```
<div class="results">
  <app-result-tile
    *ngFor="let d of service.data"
    [data]="d">
  </app-property-tile>
</div>
```

or should I do move the ngFor into the `<app-result-tile>` component?

```
<div class="results">
  <app-result-tiles
    [data]="service.data"> <!-- results now repeat internally with li's or something.-->
  </app-result-tiles>
</div>
```

I'll be writing a pipe to filter the result component(s) from the parent component. Would it make more sense to use the first method in this case?

Comment: It belong on what the <app-result-tile> will be needed to provide the service.data or every one of service.data for processing. Maybe you only use the child template working with every one of service.data so you should be used the first way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the question here is should the iterated item form a separate component or not.

The answer is YES IF the iterated item would be used on its own.

If it would ALWAYS without exception, both now and in the future, never be used on it own but always within a list, THEN the ngFor* should be used inside the child component.

If there is a pipe filtering or not on the ngFor* is irrelevant.

Comment: My only immediate concern was performance of the filtration, but I was not sure if there are other issues to consider. Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Both are valid. It depends on your usecase.

Former one would create different instances of `app-result-tiles` component and so relevant number of templates as well while later one would create one instance of your component and a single template.

Comment: I've edited my question to better explain the situation. Since my filter criteria is coming from the parent component,  should I prefer the first pattern?